# fct_reorder() in R, want to order a column in dataframe based on aother column

Tags: r

Change the `b` column of dataframe `df` to an ordered factor where the order of the levels is in increasing order based on `a` column.
I think I need to use `fct_order()` function in R.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~color,     ~a, ~b,
  "blue",      1,  2,
  "green",     100,  200,
  "purple",    2,  3,
  "red",       200,  100,
  "yellow",    3,  1
)

df$b <- factor(c(1,2,3,4,5))

df <- df  %>% 
  mutate(b = fct_reorder(b,a,.desc=TRUE))

arrange(df)
```

current output:

```
A tibble: 5 × 3
  color      a b    
  <chr>  <dbl> <fct>
1 blue       1 1    
2 green    100 2    
3 purple     2 3    
4 red      200 4    
5 yellow     3 5
```

desired output:

```
A tibble: 5 × 3
  color      a b    
  <chr>  <dbl> <fct>
1 blue       1 1    
2 green    100 4    
3 purple     2 2   
4 red      200 5    
5 yellow     3 3
```

Comment: Try with `arrange(df, b)` and you will see that `b` is ordered according to `a`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But now the output order of "b" is not according to the numeric order of "a", but alphabetical order. I tried "as.numeric(as.character(a))", but it does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question `b` should be reordered according to `a` which IMHO is exactly what `forcats::fct_reorder` or base `reorder` do.

However, your desired result is of course different from that and could be achieved by first converting the reordered `b` to a numeric and afterwards to a factor:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- df  %>% 
  mutate(b = factor(as.numeric(fct_reorder(b, a))))

arrange(df)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   color      a b    
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <fct>
#> 1 blue       1 1    
#> 2 green    100 4    
#> 3 purple     2 2    
#> 4 red      200 5    
#> 5 yellow     3 3
```